# Routing in rails app. Request being made is different from what is shown when I run rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

When I run the command below for my routes on Heroku, I get the below output.

```
[quotes_app]$heroku run rake routes
    Running rake routes on quotesappp... up, run.4768
             like_link    PUT    /links/:id/like(.:format)       links#upvote
             dislike_link PUT    /links/:id/dislike(.:format)    links#downvote
                    links GET    /links(.:format)                links#index
                          POST   /links(.:format)                links#create
                     root GET    /                               links#index
```

Now when I look at my Heroku logs after trying to test this route as an end user, I get this error:

```
Jan 12 20:35:14 quotesappp app/web.1:  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/links/1/like"): 

Jan 12 20:35:14 quotesappp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/links/1/like" host=quotesappp.herokuapp.com request_id=052c9342-2c8a-41c2-99f5-56ac9cb673c3 fwd="96.248.110.224" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=1744
```

As you can see from the Heroku raked routes I have a put request set for link/:id/like and also /dislike, but when I test it, the request comes back as a get request. Has anyone had any experience with this or may know why this is occurring?

Comment: That output is correct - there is no route for GET for like, because the route requires PUT instead. So what is generating the link (and using the wrong HTTP verb)?

Comment: How you tested your put request ? Have you sent a put request from some tool or you just type this into url and press enter. If you type url and press enter it will always send a get request to server. For test put request send request through some tool like postman for chrome etc.

Comment: from your terminal, curl it: 
curl -XPUT 'http://yoursite.whatever/links/1/like'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling a `GET` request on a `PUT` route.

The fix is to make sure you're sending the correct method:

```
<%= link_to "Like", like_link_path(@link), method: :patch %>
```

--

If you're setting the method as required, you may not have the javascript compiled in Heroku properly.

To fix this, you'll be best `precompiling` before pushing to heroku:

```
$ rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Precompiled"
$ git push heroku master
```

---

As a an aside, here's how I'd handle the routes and structure of what you're trying to achieve:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :links do
   match :like, via: [:patch, :delete], on: :member
end

#app/controllers/links_controller.rb
class LinksController < ApplicationController
   def like
      @link = Link.find params[:id]
      if request.patch?
         ...
      elsif request.delete?
         ...
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I edited my methods to become patch methods after looking at your answer and then looking into patch vs put. I tested this locally and it worked. I then precompiled my assets before pushing to heroku and it is still running a get request?

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. Can you go into your browser console and check to see if your assets / JS files are loading correctly in Heroku? To do this, you can just right-click on the page & select "inspect element". "console" is in there

Comment: I inspected the browser and it looks like I am not running my jQuery script over a secure connection based on the error below. I will change that and then see what happens.

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://quotesappp.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: nice, I don't know what I did to make it work but I'll take that! Congrats :)

Comment: the inspect element suggestion led me to see that I wasn't running my jQuery script over https, instead, http. I'm calling jQuery manually in my app.html.erb file due to a constraint I had with a gem im using. Your suggestion to look into it was what i needed

Comment: Nice man, thanks for the upvote and I hope you have a greatday